# jquery, when checkbox changes I get two alerts

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, checkbox

I dynamically generate a checkbox (just one), and I want that if this checkbox is checked, an ajax call will be made, so that the status of the value (checked or unchecked) could be save via php-file into a database.

I've not done the ajax quite yet (should be no problem) and tested it with alerts. So when the user clicks the checkbox, an alert is shown and the checkbox is checked. But when the user clicks anywhere on the same page, the alert would be repeated and the checkbox would be unchecked. THEN the user is able to click on another element on the page. What's wrong?

Heres the js:

```
function onHeadlinesLoad()
{
var hID = window.localStorage.getItem("headlineID");
window.localStorage.removeItem("headlineID");
window.localStorage.clear();

$.ajax({
       url: "headlines_getter.php?hID=" + hID ,
       success: function(data) {
       if(data){

       $("#headlinescheck").append('<label><input type="checkbox" id="headlinescheck" name="checkbox-1" value="' + hID + '" data-mini="true" /> Yes </label>');

       $("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio();
       $("#headlineshome").append(data);
       }
       }
       });

}

$("input[type='checkbox']").live('change',function() {
      alert($("input[type='checkbox']").attr('value'));
 });
```

Comment: click "anywhere"? Really anywhere?

Comment: What other scripts are loaded? Can you post the code or similar code to jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi i don't know if i have to spell it "everywhere" or "anywhere" at this context (english is not my mothertongue), but after checking the checkbox (and dismissing the alert) you could click on the content, on the navbar, on the header etc. and the checkbox would be unchecked and the alert is a second time coming.

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo i've done a jfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/S3RwK/) and this works correct... hm...

Comment: i've played arround, and found that the line `$("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio();` is doing my problems. when i delete this line everything works fine... but the line is necessary because the theme of the checkbox would be not shown without that?!

Comment: @John Brunner: sorry, I didn't mean to be rude. Just wanted to see if I understood your point. I wasn't sure what you mean with "But when the user clicks anywhere on the same page, the alert would be repeated and the checkbox would be unchecked"

Comment: @ClaudioRedi no problem, i had not understand that as an offense :) i just was not sure if the whole sentence makes another sense if i mix up "anywhere" and "everywhere".

Comment: i think the problem is solved. i've deleted the alert, and now everything works fine. maybe it's not the best way (because alerting is not working), but at the moment i just want to do a ajax call, and not an alert... so it's fine :) so, thanks guys for the help!